# Magento: Assigning product attribute sets to every product in category

Tags: magento, attributes, categories

I'm building a new website with Magento and I have 3 top tier categories (Clothing, Footwear and Accessories). I need to apply an attribute set to every product placed in these categories so users can search for Designer, Size and Colour (and potentially others later).

Is it possible to assign an attribute set to a product automatically if it is placed in a specific category, or does it have to be assigned before hand then placed in the category?

Comment: Seems like s stange way to do things, if you are creating a new Shoe to go in the Shoes category then simply use a "Shoe" attriobute set..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For product not existing you have to choose an attribute set when creating. So why don't set directly the good one ?

For existing product you have to create a script that will change attribute sets of product because you can't do this in the Backend.

If you want it to be totally automatic, you can handle this with observer, observe the product creation and the product save to set it in the right attribute set each time category changes.

Answer (score -1):

You can assign a product to a **Attribute set** only during product creation.

Comment: You can change it with a community extension or with a custom php script

Comment: I know that.But thats not what he asked.Read the question posted before downvoting answers

Comment: Remove the word "only" in your answer and I'll remove the downvote. You don't answer you say that one option is not possible. But it definitively is.